# Cannot install rpy2 in python 2.7

Tags: r, python-2.7, macos-sierra, rpy2

I am attempting to install `RPy2` in the Python environment (`2.7.x`) that comes bundled in Mac OS X Sierra (`10.12.6`), and as such, I am attempting to install the latest non-2.9.x version from Terminal using `pip` via the command:

```
pip install 'rpy2<2.9.0' --user
```

The `--user` flag is there because I have installed Homebrew on a user which is normally not admin and for which I turned on admin rights briefly for the sole purpose of installing Homebrew.

Every time I run this command, I get the following error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1x/d_trx3556sl61by_tp4093j80000gq/T/pip-build-uV52fY/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/1x/d_trx3556sl61by_tp4093j80000gq/T/pip-LoW5FN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1x/d_trx3556sl61by_tp4093j80000gq/T/pip-build-uV52fY/rpy2/
```

Looking back into the output, it shows the following at time of failure:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy/rinterface
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
unable to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7': No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7' failed with exit status 1
```

I am unable to find anyone who is getting a similar error, and I cannot figure out what is going on.
Does anyone know why this is failing?

Comment: In the end, I used Homebrew to install `python 3.4.x` and just used that - however, an answer would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage you from installing Python packages in your system's Python (unless you are happy with reinstalling the system if "something suddenly stopped working").

I also encourage you to use the latest rpy2 (the 2.9.x series are arguably much better than the 2.8.x series), and move to Python 3.

Finally, a binary wheel for rpy2-2.9.3 on OS X is now available on pypi (making the installation no longer require a development tools).